How to make Sparce Matirx operations faster?
Sparse matrix are matrices that the vast majority of elements are 0s, with only a few non-zero elements.Now I have to fill my Sparsematrix class such that matrices can do add,subtract,and multiply.
I use COO to store my matrix.
template <class T>
class VecList{
    private:
        int capacity;
        int length;
        T* arr;
        void doubleListSize(){
            T * oldArr = arr;
            arr = new T[2*capacity];
            capacity = 2 * capacity;
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                arr[i] = oldArr[i];
            }
            delete [] oldArr;
        }
    public:
        VecList(){
            length = 0;
            capacity = 100;
            arr = new T[capacity];
        }
        VecList(T* a, int n){
            length = n;
            capacity = 100 + 2*n;
            arr = new T[capacity];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                arr[i] = a[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                cout << arr[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            printList();
        }
        ~VecList(){
            delete [] arr;
        }
        int getLength(){
            return length;
        }
        bool isEmpty(){
            return length==0;
        }
        void insertEleAtPos(int i, T x){
            if(length==capacity)
                doubleListSize();
            if(i > length || i < 0)
                throw "Illegal position";
            for(int j=length;j>i;j--)
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            arr[i] = x;
            length++;
        }
        T deleteEleAtPos(int i){
            if(i >= length || i < 0)
                throw "Illegal position";
            T tmp = arr[i];
            for(int j=i;j<length-1;j++)
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            length--;
            return tmp;
        }
        void setEleAtPos(int i, T x){
            if(i >= length || i < 0)
                throw "Illegal position";
            arr[i] = x;
        }
        T getEleAtPos(int i){
            if(i >= length || i < 0)
                throw "Illegal position";
            return arr[i];
        }
        int locateEle(T x){
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                if(arr[i]==x)
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        void printList(){
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
                cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
};

COO is using three VecList to store a matrix.

rowIndex: Indicates the number of rows.
colIndex: Indicates the number of cols.
values: Indicates the value of elements.
Below is my Sparsematrix class:

template <class T>
class SparseMatrix{
    private:
        int rows;
        int cols;
        VecList<int>* rowIndex;
        VecList<int>* colIndex;
        VecList<T>* values;
    public:
        SparseMatrix(){ //Create a 10x10 Sparse matrix
            rows = 10;
            cols = 10;
            rowIndex = new VecList<int>();
            colIndex = new VecList<int>();
            values = new VecList<T>();
        }
        SparseMatrix(int r, int c){ //Create a rxc Sparse matrix
            rows = r;
            cols = c;
            rowIndex = new VecList<int>();
            colIndex = new VecList<int>();
            values = new VecList<T>();
        }
        ~SparseMatrix(){
            delete rowIndex;
            delete colIndex;
            delete values;
        }
};

As you can see, I only need to focus on the non-zero elements. So for exaple: A sparse matrix
0 2 0
0 0 1
3 0 0

rows = Exact number of rows, 3
cols = Exact number of columns, 3
rowIndex = 0 1 2
colIndex = 1 2 0
values   = 2 1 3

The first vertical line means that, row[0]col[1] has a non-zero element "2".
The second vertical line means that, row[1]col[2] has a non-zero element "1".
And now I wirte several functions to achieve operations between matrices.
int findPos(int a, int b){ //If there is a non-zero element at (a, b), then return its position in            "rowIndex", else return -1.
            for (int i = 0; i < rowIndex->getLength(); i++)
            {
                 if(rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i) == a && colIndex->getEleAtPos(i) == b)return i;
                 else if(rowIndex->getEleAtPos(rowIndex->getLength() - 1 - i) == a && colIndex->getEleAtPos(colIndex->getLength()-1-i) == b)return rowIndex->getLength()-1 - i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        void setEntry(int rPos, int cPos, T x){ // Set (rPos, cPos) = x
            int pos = findPos(rPos,cPos);
            //Find if there is a non-zero element at (rPos, cPos).
            if(x != 0){
            //If the origin matrix does not have an element at(rPos, cPos),insert x to the matrix.
            if (pos == -1)
            {
                rowIndex->insertEleAtPos(rowIndex->getLength(),rPos);
                colIndex->insertEleAtPos(colIndex->getLength(),cPos);
                values->insertEleAtPos(values->getLength(),x);
            }
            else{
                //If the origin matrix has an element at(rPos, cPos),replace it with x.
                rowIndex->setEleAtPos(pos,rPos);
                colIndex->setEleAtPos(pos,cPos);
                values->setEleAtPos(pos,x);
            }
           }
           else{
            //If x == 0 and the origin matrix has an element at(rPos, cPos), delete the element.
                if(pos != -1){
                    rowIndex->deleteEleAtPos(pos);
                    colIndex->deleteEleAtPos(pos);
                    values->deleteEleAtPos(pos);
                }
            }
        //If x == 0, and the origin matrix does not have an element at(rPos, cPos), nothing changed.
        }
T getEntry(int rPos, int cPos){
        //Get the element at (rPos, cPos)
            return findPos(rPos,cPos) == -1 ? 0 : values->getEleAtPos(findPos(rPos,cPos));
        }
        SparseMatrix<T> * add(SparseMatrix<T> * B){
            if(rows != B->rows || cols != B->cols)throw "Matrices have incompatible sizes";
            SparseMatrix<T> *C = new SparseMatrix<T>(rows,cols);//Create a new matrix C as result.
            for (int i = 0; i < rowIndex->getLength(); i++)
            {
//I call the two input matrices "A" and "B". I put every elements of A into C, and also put every elements of B into C. But I use "C->setEntry", which means when A[i][j] has an element and B[i][j] also has an element, "setEntry" will cover the prior one. So I use C->setEntry(i,j,C->getEntry(i,j) + A[i][j] or B[i][j]), in another word, setEntry with (oldvalue + newvalue).That's what I did.
                C->setEntry(rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),colIndex->getEleAtPos(i),C->getEntry(rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),colIndex->getEleAtPos(i))+values->getEleAtPos(i));
                C->setEntry(B->rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),B->colIndex->getEleAtPos(i),C->getEntry(B->rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),B->colIndex->getEleAtPos(i))+B->values->getEleAtPos(i));
            }
            return C;
        }
        SparseMatrix<T> * subtract(SparseMatrix<T> * B){
//The same method as add.
            if(rows != B->rows || cols != B->cols)throw "Matrices have incompatible sizes";
            SparseMatrix<T> *C = new SparseMatrix<T>(rows,cols);
            for (int i = 0; i < rowIndex->getLength(); i++)
            {
                C->setEntry(rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),colIndex->getEleAtPos(i),C->getEntry(rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),colIndex->getEleAtPos(i))-values->getEleAtPos(i));
                C->setEntry(B->rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),B->colIndex->getEleAtPos(i),C->getEntry(B->rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),B->colIndex->getEleAtPos(i))-B->values->getEleAtPos(i));
            }
            return C;
        }

        SparseMatrix<T> * multiply(SparseMatrix<T> * B){
            //perform multiplication if the sizes of the matrices are compatible.
            if(rows != B->cols || cols != B->rows)throw "Matrices have incompatible sizes"; 
            SparseMatrix<T> *C = new SparseMatrix<T>(rows,B->cols);
//I call the two input matrices as "A" and "B".
//My method is take a row of A first, let this row do the arithmetic with each column of B，then I finish a row in C. Then continue to the next row.
            for (int i = 0; i < rowIndex->getLength();i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < B->colIndex->getLength(); j++)
                {
                    if (B->findPos(colIndex->getEleAtPos(i),B->colIndex->getEleAtPos(j)) != -1)
                    {
                        C->setEntry(rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),B->colIndex->getEleAtPos(j),C->getEntry(rowIndex->getEleAtPos(i),B->colIndex->getEleAtPos(j))+(values->getEleAtPos(i)*B->values->getEleAtPos(j)));
                    }
                } 
            }
            return C;
        }

        void printMatrix(){
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    cout << getEntry(i,j) << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }

I've tested for several conditions and all of them shows that the add,subtract and multiply are doing well. But there's a 10000x10000 matrix(called "X" and "Y") test that I can't pass, X and Y does not have many non-zero elements.And they just do add, subtract and multiply.
The time limit is 1 sec.(Not including printMatrix(), but including setEntry()) I exceeded it.How do I reduce the running time of my programme? (I also wonder if the COO storage is wrong, and if the findPos() funcion is spare.)Thank you.
My tool is VSCode2022, with C++11, Windows 11.
Here is a sample of the test code.
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    SparseMatrix<int> X,Y;
    X.setEntry(1,3,4);
    X.setEntry(7,8,2);
    Y.setEntry(1,6,4);
    Y.setEntry(1,3,4);
    Y.setEntry(7,7,2);
    X.printMatrix();
    cout << endl;
    Y.printMatrix();
    cout << endl;
    X.add(&Y)->printMatrix();
    cout << endl;
    X.subtract(&Y)->printMatrix();
    cout << endl;
    Y.multiply(&X)->printMatrix();
    cout << "Done" << endl;
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count();
    cout << "Running Time:" << duration << "ms\n";
    return 0;
}


Range checking is good, but not for speed. When you multiply two 10000x10000 matrices, the code will call getEleAtPos a couple of hundred million times. Even though we know they are within range (because of the loop conditions).

Unrelated: your code would be a whole lot clearer if you used some temporary variables eg acol = colIndex->getEleAtPos(i)

There's no reason at all for any of the members of SparseMatrix to be pointers, so you can immediately speed things up by taking the pointers away.


After two days of hard work, I got ACCEPTED in the test. Two 10000x10000 Sparse Matrices' operations are completed in 0.01s~0.02s.

And I have to say that use three VecList or any two-dimensional array to store a sparce matrix is absolutely not a good idea. Because there are thousands of 0s in the matrix. This time I use only one VecList to store a matrix, but in the VecList are struct rHead members.


struct OrthNode{
    /*I apologize for misspelling ‘row’ as ‘rol’.It was only when the program 
    was mostly written that I noticed this.*/
    int rol, col, value;
    struct OrthNode *right;
};
struct rHead{
    int nums;
//This variable 'nums' is useless.I didn't use it in the later program.
    struct OrthNode * right;
};


The rHead are contained in VecList, how much rows a matrix has, then how many rHead are in the VecList. Each rHead leads a whole row, when I want to visit a row, I should visit its rHead first.
The OrthNode is like an ID-Card. It record all informations of a non-zero element, its col, itsrol, itsvalue. And it's worth noting that it has a *right which points to the next element in the same row.
Now, I use the rHead as the beginning of each row. And rHead->right points to the first non-zero element, an OrthNode, in this row. And this OrthNode's pointer OrthNode->right points to the next element in this row.No matter rHead or OrthNode,if there's no element on the right side, then it points to NULL.
In this way, when I want to visit A[3][4], first visit the rHead of the third row, that is VecList[3].Now I am at A[3][?],then find rHead->right,suppose it is rHead->right = A[3][1], then findA[3][1]->right, until I get A[3][4].
So I use one VecList to store a sparse matrix row by row. I put the elements in each row in the order of the columns(For example in row[3], rHead->A[3][1]->A[3][2]->A[3][4]->A[3][6].Say, A[3][k],the k is in order.)
Here is my code:

template <class T>
class VecList{
//Only this member funcion has changed, so that it can return a correct thing.
public:
        T* getEleAtPos(int i){
            if(i >= length || i < 0)
                throw "Illegal position";
            return &arr[i];
        }
//Others things in VecList are the same as in question.
};
template <class T>
class SparseMatrix{
    private:
        VecList<rHead> M;//The VecList is the same as in the question.
        int totalrows;
        int totalcols;
    public:
        SparseMatrix(){
            totalrows = 10;
            totalcols = 10;
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                M.insertEleAtPos(M.getLength(), {0, nullptr});
            }
        }
        SparseMatrix(int r, int c){
            totalrows = r;
            totalcols = c;
            for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
                M.insertEleAtPos(M.getLength(), {0, nullptr});
            }
        }
        ~SparseMatrix(){
            for (int i = 0; i < totalrows; i++)
            {
                if(M.getEleAtPos(i)->right != NULL)
                {
                    OrthNode * temp = M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    while (temp != NULL)
                    {
                        M.getEleAtPos(i)->right = temp->right;
                        OrthNode*delNode = temp;
                        temp = temp->right;
                        delete delNode;
                    }
                    delete temp;
                }
            }
        }
        void setEntry(int rPos, int cPos, T x){
            OrthNode* newNode = new OrthNode;
            newNode->rol = rPos;
            newNode->col = cPos;
            newNode->value = x;
            if (x == 0)
            {
                if (M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->right == NULL)
                {
                    delete newNode;
                    return;
                }
                OrthNode*temp = M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->right;
                if (temp->col == cPos)
                {
                    M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->right = temp->right;
                    delete newNode;
                    delete temp;
                    M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->nums --;
                    return;
                }
                
                while(temp->col < cPos && temp != NULL){
                    if (temp->right->col == cPos)
                    {
                        OrthNode*delNode = temp->right;
                        temp = temp->right->right;
                        delete delNode;
                        M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->nums --;
                        return;
                    }
                    temp = temp->right;
                }
                if (temp->right == NULL)
                {
                    delete temp;
                    delete newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else{
                if (M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->right == NULL)
                {
                    newNode->right = NULL;
                    M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->right = newNode;
                    M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->nums ++;
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    OrthNode* temp = M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->right;
                    if (cPos < temp->col)
                    {
                        newNode->right = temp;
                        M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->right = newNode;
                        M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->nums ++;
                        return;
                    }
                    while (temp->col <= cPos && temp != NULL)
                    {
                        if (temp->col == cPos)
                        {
                            temp->value = x;
                            M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->nums ++;
                            delete newNode;
                            return;
                        }
                        if (temp->right == NULL)
                        {
                            newNode->right =NULL;
                            temp->right = newNode;
                            M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->nums ++;
                            return;
                        } 
                        if (temp->col < cPos && temp->right->col > cPos)
                        {
                            newNode->right = temp->right;
                            temp->right = newNode;
                            M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->nums ++;
                            return;
                        }
                        temp = temp->right;
                    }    
            }
        }
    }
        T getEntry(int rPos, int cPos){
            OrthNode* read = new OrthNode;
            read = M.getEleAtPos(rPos)->right;
            while (read != NULL)
            {
                if (read->col == cPos)
                {
                    return read->value;
                }
                read = read->right;
            }
            delete read;
            return 0;
        }
        SparseMatrix<T> * add(SparseMatrix<T> * B){
            if(totalrows != B->totalrows || totalcols != B->totalcols)throw "Matrices have incompatible sizes";
            SparseMatrix<T>* C = new SparseMatrix(totalrows,totalcols);
            for (int i = 0; i < totalrows; i++)
            {
                if (M.getEleAtPos(i)->right != NULL && B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right == NULL)
                {
                    OrthNode * tempA = M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    while (tempA != NULL)
                    {
                        C->setEntry(tempA->rol,tempA->col,tempA->value);
                        tempA = tempA->right;
                    }
                    delete tempA;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (M.getEleAtPos(i)->right == NULL && B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right != NULL)
                {
                    OrthNode * tempB = B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    while (tempB != NULL)
                    {
                        C->setEntry(tempB->rol,tempB->col,tempB->value);
                        tempB = tempB->right;
                    }
                    delete tempB;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (M.getEleAtPos(i)->right == NULL && B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right == NULL)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    OrthNode * tempA = M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    OrthNode * tempB = B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    while (tempA != NULL)
                    {
                        C->setEntry(tempA->rol,tempA->col,tempA->value);
                        tempA = tempA->right;
                    }
                    delete tempA;
                    while (tempB != NULL)
                    {
                        int oldEntry = C->getEntry(tempB->rol,tempB->col);
                        C->setEntry(tempB->rol,tempB->col,oldEntry + tempB->value);
                        tempB = tempB->right;
                    }
                    delete tempB;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        return C;
        }
        SparseMatrix<T> * subtract(SparseMatrix<T> * B){
            if(totalrows != B->totalrows || totalcols != B->totalcols)throw "Matrices have incompatible sizes";
            SparseMatrix<T>* C = new SparseMatrix(totalrows,totalcols);
            for (int i = 0; i < totalrows; i++)
            {
                if (M.getEleAtPos(i)->right != NULL && B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right == NULL)
                {
                    OrthNode * tempA = M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    while (tempA != NULL)
                    {
                        C->setEntry(tempA->rol,tempA->col,tempA->value);
                        tempA = tempA->right;
                    }
                    delete tempA;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (M.getEleAtPos(i)->right == NULL && B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right != NULL)
                {
                    OrthNode * tempB = B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    while (tempB != NULL)
                    {
                        C->setEntry(tempB->rol,tempB->col, -(tempB->value));
                        tempB = tempB->right;
                    }
                    delete tempB;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (M.getEleAtPos(i)->right == NULL && B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right == NULL)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    OrthNode * tempA = M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    OrthNode * tempB = B->M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    while (tempA != NULL)
                    {
                        C->setEntry(tempA->rol,tempA->col,tempA->value);
                        tempA = tempA->right;
                    }
                    delete tempA;
                    while (tempB != NULL)
                    {
                        int oldEntry = C->getEntry(tempB->rol,tempB->col);
                        C->setEntry(tempB->rol,tempB->col,oldEntry - tempB->value);
                        tempB = tempB->right;
                    }
                    delete tempB;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        return C;
        }

        SparseMatrix<T> * multiply(SparseMatrix<T> * B){
            //perform multiplication if the sizes of the matrices are compatible.
            if (totalrows != B->totalcols || totalcols != B->totalrows)throw "Matrices have incompatible sizes";
            SparseMatrix<T>* C = new SparseMatrix(totalrows,B->totalcols);
            for (int i = 0; i < totalrows; i++)
            {
                if (M.getEleAtPos(i)->right == NULL)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    OrthNode* tempA = M.getEleAtPos(i)->right;
                    while (tempA != NULL)
                    {
                        if (B->M.getEleAtPos(tempA->col) != NULL)
                        {
                        OrthNode* tempB = B->M.getEleAtPos(tempA->col)->right;
                        while (tempB != NULL)
                            {
                                int oldEntry = C->getEntry(tempA->rol,tempB->col);
                                C->setEntry(tempA->rol,tempB->col,oldEntry + tempA->value * tempB->value);
                                tempB = tempB->right;
                            }
                        }
                        tempA = tempA->right;
                    }  
                }
            }
            return C;
        }

        // Only call this function if you know the size of matrix is reasonable.
        void printMatrix(){
            // for (int i = 0; i < totalrows; i++)
            // {
            //     for (int j = 0; j < totalcols; j++)
            //     {
            //         cout << getEntry(i,j) << " ";
            //     }
            //     cout << endl;
            // }
            cout << "Be careful, when the matrix is too big, do not use Print!" << endl;
        }


And here is the test code:

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    SparseMatrix<int> X(10,10);
    SparseMatrix<int> Y(10,10);
//It is a Sparse Matrix so do not give so much elements.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        X.setEntry(i,i,2);
        Y.setEntry(3,i,i+2);
    }
//If you want to test the time cost, do not use printMatrix();
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    X.printMatrix();
    cout << endl;
    Y.printMatrix();
    cout << endl;
    X.add(&Y)->printMatrix();
    cout << endl;
    X.subtract(&Y)->printMatrix();
    cout << endl;
    X.multiply(&Y)->printMatrix();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Done" << endl;
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count();
    cout << "Running Time:" << duration << "ms\n";
    return 0;
}


I'm not sure this can still be called a sparse matrix. A 1Bx1B sparse matrix  (empty or otherwise) should not take up 8GB of Ram, in my opinion.

Running memory is really a big issue.No matter there is an element or not in a row, I created a rHead pointer. A more optimized algorithm is add *next in struct rHead such that rHead->next points to the next rHead who has an element. When there are no elements in a row, then no rHead in that row. Furthermore, create a cHead that leads a whole column is convinient for storage and location. When cHead is created, then every OrthNode has to add a *down pointer which points to the element underneath it. However, it's possible that I didn't properly delete the allocated memory.

.. Which willake your getPos operator O(n) again. You need a tree structure of some kind or at least a binary search.

Some quick back-of-the envelope calculation first: your findPos is O(n) with n the number of items in the matrix. your multiply call has two nested for loops. The inner loop calls findPos at least once, and possibly two more times for the getEntry and setEntry calls.
As a first improvement, consider keeping your rowIndex and colIndex sorted by row first and then by column. This allows using an obscure algorithm called binary search, which is O(log n).
Additionally, it allows you to quickly select all elements that belong to a given row.
This also makes your add and subtract functions much simpler: you just walk both matrices simultaneously and either copy elements to the result matrix do the occasional addition/subtraction if both matrices have that position filled.
The second optimization is then another common one: in a multiplication A * B, the A matrix is read row by row and B is read column by column. Thus, if you transpose B first you can read it row by row which – as stated above – is now fast.

"obscure algorithm called binary search" obscure?

that's the joke ;) This seems to be homework for a C++ or algorithms/datastructures class, so OP should know about binary search.

Thanks for your advice. It is easy to understand binary search, but it means that I have to sort the rowIndex after add,subtract and multiply? By the way, I don't actually understand what is sorted by row first and then by column.

I meant that cells within the same row should appear in increasing order in your colIndex array. You can structure your add, multiply, sub operations such that they only ever produce indices in the correct order.
